# Differential Change does i need to program transmission

Tags: dodge, rear-differential, tuning

I change my rear differential from 2.62 to 3.09 on a RT Dodge but I realized that the rpm is higher so this will cause more fuel consumption. So can i programe it so that the rpm will act the same when 2.62 was installed?

Comment: I mean program the transmission

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about how the transmission shifts and such, yes you should get it tuned. The computer thinks it has the lower gear in there and is trying to shift the transmission as such. It should also allow for the speedometer to register correctly as well. Tuning this should be real easy. Most vehicles have one value which needs to be changed and that's it. It does take special equipment/software to do it, though.